# Enable horizontal scrolling for line chart in SAPUI5

Tags: scroll, sapui5

I have a VizFrame line chart similar to [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame/sample/sap.viz.sample.Line) example.
[image: Line chart]

Zooming in and out on a device with touchpad works just as expected. However, scrolling horizontally does not work whereas it does work on e.g. [tables](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Basic). Is it possible to enable such a functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did u try  the Scrollcontainer ? https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ScrollContainer%23constructor

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work for me. But maybe I'm doing it wrong, idk